# tensorflow is being installed in anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Tags: virtualenv, tensorflow

I'm trying to install `tensorflow` in `virtualenv`

after installing I get the message that tensorflow has been installed in 
`/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

how can I get it installed in site-packages of virtual environment?

**EDIT**

I'm using ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
and following are the sequence of instructions I executed

`sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev python-virtualenv`

`virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/tensorflow`

`cd ~/tensorflow`

`source bin/activate`

I encountered   `tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

when trying to execute

`pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`

so I had to follow instuction from https://askubuntu.com/questions/695981/platform-not-supported-for-tensorflow-on-ubuntu-14-04-2

so after executing

`python2.7 -m pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`

I got the output

```
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.10.0 in /home/sasidhar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==0.5.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.9.2 in /home/sasidhar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==0.5.0)
Installing collected packages: tensorflow
Installing collected packages: tensorflow
Found existing installation: tensorflow 0.5.0
Uninstalling tensorflow-0.5.0:
  Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-0.5.0
Successfully installed tensorflow-0.5.0
```

so as I'm trying to install in virtual environment, I want to install `tensorflow` locally in virtual environment rather than in `/home/sasidhar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: How have you tried to install it, what OS? It is not a place for guessing.

Comment: sorry sir,
added the steps I followed while installing

Answer (score 0):

It seems you already have anaconda installed. anaconda comes with an environment management system, already (see [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html)). Having two systems (virtualenv and anaconda) seems to mess up your python paths.

If you would like  to use conda environments, then you do not need to install virtualenv. Just create a new conda env for your tensorflow installation.

If you still have troubles with your installation, you can have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34746395/588709). It's for Mac OS X, but the steps described should work on any system.