# Tensor flow install OSX

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to install TensorFlow on El 10.11.1, and I'm having issues creating and installing the pip package that I do not understand at all.

I successfully installed Bazel, SWIG and NumPy [per instructions](http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md) (at least they all seem to work at this time).

Creating the pip package/install I get the following error when I run the command:

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

> /Users/christophermichael/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:730:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/python:_pywrap_tensorflow.so' failed: osx_gcc_wrapper.sh failed: error executing command

Running with `--verbose_failures`, I get:

> ```
> /Users/christophermichael/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:730:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/python:_pywrap_tensorflow.so' failed: osx_gcc_wrapper.sh failed: error executing command 
> (cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_christophermichael/b14fc0915a4b8dd526e88d50650b0640/tensorflow && \
>   exec env - \
>     INTERCEPT_LOCALLY_EXECUTABLE=1 \
>     PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/christophermichael/bin \
>     TMPDIR=/var/folders/tv/rgqv4fp54mn952pn_v0tjwt80000gn/T/ \
>   tools/cpp/osx_gcc_wrapper.sh '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -fcolor-diagnostics -Wall -Wthread-safety -Wself-assign -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections '-std=c++0x' -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles -isystem google/protobuf/src -isystem bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles/google/protobuf/src -isystem tools/cpp/gcc3 -isystem external/jpeg_archive/jpeg-9a -isystem bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles/external/jpeg_archive/jpeg-9a -isystem external/png_archive/libpng-1.2.53 -isystem bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles/external/png_archive/libpng-1.2.53 -isystem external/re2 -isystem bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles/external/re2 -isystem third_party/gpus/cuda -isystem bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles/third_party/gpus/cuda -isystem third_party/gpus/cuda/include -isystem bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles/third_party/gpus/cuda/include -isystem third_party/eigen3 -isystem bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles/third_party/eigen3 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -Wno-self-assign -Wno-write-strings -I/usr/include/python2.7 -no-canonical-prefixes -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/_objs/_pywrap_tensorflow.so/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.pic.o' -MD -MF bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/_objs/_pywrap_tensorflow.so/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.pic.d -fPIC -c bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.cc -o bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/_objs/_pywrap_tensorflow.so/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.pic.o): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1: osx_gcc_wrapper.sh failed: error executing command 
>   (cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_christophermichael/b14fc0915a4b8dd526e88d50650b0640/tensorflow && \
>   exec env - \
>     INTERCEPT_LOCALLY_EXECUTABLE=1 \
>     PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/christophermichael/bin \
>     TMPDIR=/var/folders/tv/rgqv4fp54mn952pn_v0tjwt80000gn/T/ \
>   tools/cpp/osx_gcc_wrapper.sh '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -fcolor-diagnostics -Wall -Wthread-safety -Wself-assign -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections '-std=c++0x' -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles -isystem google/protobuf/src -isystem bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles/google/protobuf/src -isystem tools/cpp/gcc3 -isystem external/jpeg_archive/jpeg-9a -isystem bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles/external/jpeg_archive/jpeg-9a -isystem external/png_archive/libpng-1.2.53 -isystem bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles/external/png_archive/libpng-1.2.53 -isystem external/re2 -isystem bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles/external/re2 -isystem third_party/gpus/cuda -isystem bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles/third_party/gpus/cuda -isystem third_party/gpus/cuda/include -isystem bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles/third_party/gpus/cuda/include -isystem third_party/eigen3 -isystem bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/genfiles/third_party/eigen3 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -Wno-self-assign -Wno-write-strings -I/usr/include/python2.7 -no-canonical-prefixes -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/_objs/_pywrap_tensorflow.so/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.pic.o' -MD -MF bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/_objs/_pywrap_tensorflow.so/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.pic.d -fPIC -c bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.cc -o bazel-out/local_darwin-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/_objs/_pywrap_tensorflow.so/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.pic.o): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
> Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
> INFO: Elapsed time: 4.940s, Critical Path: 3.69s
> ```

Comment: ouch my eyes,  *wall of code... *

Comment: Can you narrow the error down to what is relevant?

Comment: I think that something is wrong with gcc?  I'm pretty far over my head here trying to install this:    /Users/christophermichael/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:730:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/python:_pywrap_tensorflow.so' failed: osx_gcc_wrapper.sh failed

Comment: mind typing `gcc --version` and `g++ --version` into your terminal and pasting your results?

Comment: MooseBook:~ christophermichael$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: MooseBook:~ christophermichael$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to install from source?

Create a virtualenv and install it there, I have the same OS version and it works super fine from this method:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33691154/1973820

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  I have never used virtualenv and thought it might be easier to install from source.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, as Hamed said above, it's better directly install the binaries.

However, if you do need to build from the source, then these steps should work:

- `brew install python`
- `virtualenv ~/tf`
- `source ~/tf/bin/activate`
- Install bazel for Mac
- Install PCRE (not PCRE2) for Mac
- Install SWIG for Mac
- `git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow`
- `cd tensorflow`
- `./configure`
- `bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`
- `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg`
- `pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`
- `bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer`

Comment: In my case I add to change `pip install...` in `pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-0.8.0-py2-none-any.whl `

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to install anaconda and use its environment management. The advantage of using environments either with anaconda or virtualenv is that you separate sources and dependencies for different use cases. This means, if you need to make changes to your python libraries for something else, it won't affect your tensorflow environmnet.

Here is how to install tensorflow with anaconda.

1. Install anaconda http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install
2. Create a new conda workspace
3. Download the specific protobuf version that tensorflow needs: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf/3.0.0a3
4. Install it via `sudo easy_install ~/Downloads/protobuf-3.0.0a3-py2.7.egg`
5. Install a numpy version greater than 1.08.x via `conda install numpy`
6. Download the 0.6.0 version of tensorflow:
   https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.6.0-py2-none-any.whl
7. Install via `pip install ~/Downloads/tensorflow-0.6.0-py2-none-any.whl`

When you install
    tensorflow from the whl file directly, it should tell you when
    dependencies are not there. It seems not to be able to resolve these
    conflicts independently. My setup had issues with protobuf and
    numpy. After installing them manually everything worked fine.

I hope this helps!